# Aspose slides 'Area chart' series value not shown in the tooltip

Tags: java, aspose, aspose-slides

I am using aspose-slides-17.3-jdk16.jar for java. I have created the Area Chart using IChartDataWorkbook and I'm able to get the series values in the tool tip for all the charts except Area chart.

Following is the code I have done so far.

```
public class AreaChartSlide {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Presentation pres = new Presentation();

ISlide slide = pres.getSlides().get_Item(0);

// Creating the default chart
IChart chart = slide.getShapes().addChart(ChartType.Area, 0, 0, 500, 400);

// Getting the default chart data worksheet index
int defaultWorksheetIndex = 0;

// Getting the chart data worksheet
IChartDataWorkbook fact = chart.getChartData().getChartDataWorkbook();

// Delete demo series
chart.getChartData().getSeries().clear();


// Add new series
chart.getChartData().getSeries().add(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 0, 1, "Series 1"), chart.getType());
chart.getChartData().getSeries().add(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 0, 2, "Series 2"), chart.getType());

// Adding new categories
chart.getChartData().getCategories().add(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 0, "Cat 1"));
chart.getChartData().getCategories().add(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 0, "Cat 2"));

// Take first chart series
IChartSeries series = chart.getChartData().getSeries().get_Item(0);
// Now populating series data
series.getDataPoints().addDataPointForAreaSeries(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 1, 1, 20));
series.getDataPoints().addDataPointForAreaSeries(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 2, 50));
// Setting fill color for series
series.getFormat().getFill().setFillType(FillType.Solid);
series.getFormat().getFill().getSolidFillColor().setColor(Color.RED);

// Take second chart series
series = chart.getChartData().getSeries().get_Item(1);
// Now populating series data
series.getDataPoints().addDataPointForAreaSeries(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 1, 30));
series.getDataPoints().addDataPointForAreaSeries(fact.getCell(defaultWorksheetIndex, 2, 2, 10));
series.getFormat().getFill().setFillType(FillType.Solid);
series.getFormat().getFill().getSolidFillColor().setColor(Color.GREEN);

pres.save("E:/PPT/Aspose.pptx", SaveFormat.Pptx);
System.out.println("done");

}
```

Below is the chart output i got
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with shared sample code using [Aspose.Slides for Java 17.5](https://downloads.aspose.com/slides/java/new-releases/aspose.slides-for-java-17.5/) on my end and have generated a presentation with Area chart having two series and two categories. I have opened the generated presentation in PowerPoint and able to observe the tool-tip text for both chart series. Please observe [Series 1](https://prnt.sc/fho3l5) and [Series 2](https://prnt.sc/fho3ir) tool-tip text display for your kind reference. I hope the shared information will be helpful. Please share, if I may help you further in this regard.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

We are sorry for your inconvenience.

Comment: Please refer this [Bar Chart](https://prnt.sc/fhqqtv) as you can see the value of the Series, but in [Area Chart](https://prnt.sc/fhqpmr) the value of the series is not shown

Answer (score 0):

I have observed your comments and comparison image of tool-tip text display for Bar chart and Area chart. I like to add here that this is not some issue in Aspose.Slides charting engine but its a PowerPoint implementation. If you add an Area chart using PowerPoint, that too will display the point and series name in tool-tip text. Please observe the tool-tip text for slides 2 and 3 in [this presentation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzvMFhwg29yEMVlYcTIzY2NFQTg/view?usp=sharing). You can observe in [this snapshot](https://prnt.sc/fi4wst) as well that tool-tip text for PowerPoint generated chart is also displaying series and point as it is being shown for similar chart type generated using Aspose.Slides. I hope the shared information will be helpful.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Many Thanks.